# iPhone CoreData migration of data only

Tags: iphone, core-data, data-migration

I have an iPhone application that uses CoreData for storage.

The persistent store (an sqlite3 database) is shipped with several of its entities populated with data. These data are used to create various menus and options in the application. Let's call these data "application data".

Several other entities are used by the application to store user data.

Although the schema rarely changes, I often need to update the application data to provide new options to users.

I have a MacRuby script that gets the new data from a bunch of CSV files and updates the sqlite3 database on my development machine, but I am not sure what is the best way to update existing deployed apps with the new application data (remember, no schema change) without affecting the user data.

Any ideas?

**_*Update*_**

After a bit of thinking, I am getting oriented towards setting the application to download a new sqlite3 file from a web server that contains the new data. Once received, my app will copy the data from the update sqlite3 file into the app's working database file, completely replacing the application data, but not touching the user data.

A mechanism for determining if an update has been applied can use a text file with a single database version number which the app will download periodically. If this number is larger than the number of the previous update (which is stored locally), then the update will proceed, otherwise it will ignore it.

Comment: Hi Futureshocked, have you found the answer. I am also facing the same issue. I have a entity called DefaultValues which i want to update with few new records without touching users data present into other entities. Don't know what exactly i have to do??

Comment: I haven't finished this yet, but the strategy I plan to follow is to bundle the new data in a sqlite3 file (although this doesn't matter, it could just be a simple json file), have it downloaded on the iPhone by the app, then opened and have the data copied as required in the app's own database. Hope this helps. I have implemented the part that download the sqlite3 file on the phone, then got short of time :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you are just talking about adding new entries into the sqlite3 store is there a reason you couldn't do so on application launch?  I haven't had to do this myself, but I don't see why you couldn't create a property list containing the data you need inserted and perform the updates on application launch.

```
NSString *applicationDataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ApplicationData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *previousVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"VERSION"];

NSString *currentVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

/* Don't bother processing updates if the version last run  is the same as the current version. */
if (! [previousVersion isEqualToString:currentVersion])
{
   NSArray *versionList = [applicationData objectForKey:@"Versions"];

   BOOL process = (nil == previousVersion);
   for (NSDictionary *versionData in versionList)
   {
     NSString *version = [versionData objectForKey:@"version"];
     if (process)
     {
       // Send dictionary for this version update to some method to process it..
       [self processUpdate:versionData];
     }

     if (!process && [version isEqualToString:previousVersion])
       process = YES;
   }
}
```

Idea being that the plist contains an array of dictionary describing each version of the application and the data that should updated for this version.  The plist example I have below is lacking any required details so is just a stub to get the idea.

Also, no idea if the code actually works ;)  Just how I think I might do it if I had to deal with the same thing, assuming I understand your issue correctly.

Should also note that with this you would want to update the previous version that is stored in user defaults on app launch after the data is updated so that it only runs once.

[{
    Versions = (
    {
        data = {
            1 = {
                entity = Menu;
            };
        };
        version = "1.1";
    },
    {
        data = {
            1 = {
                entity = Menu;
            };
        };
        version = "1.2";
    },
    {
        data = {
            1 = {
                entity = Menu;
            };
        };
        version = "1.3";
    },
    {
        data = {
            1 = {
                entity = Menu;
            };
        };
        version = "2.0";
    },
    {
        data = {
            1 = {
                entity = Menu;
            };
        };
        version = "2.5";
    }
    );
}]

Comment: Thanks Mike, this is not exactly matching my situation. I have a sqlite3 database used for persistence by CoreData in my app. The DB is ~4MB, and contains two sets of tables: one that holds user data, and one that holds application data. The bulk of the DB is application data, and it is this that I need to be able to replace with a new set (without affecting the user data).